# Unable to do-release-upgrade

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I do have proper internet access and my current IP (in the UK) is `82.47.29.14` but my laptop is still linked to the German server `91.189.91.24 80`.

But now I am unable to do `do-release-upgrade`:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Err Upgrade tool signature                                                                                                                                              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]                                                                                                                                  
Err Upgrade tool                                                                                                                                                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]                                                                                                                                  
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                               
WARNING:root:file 'utopic.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem. 
alvas@ubi:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Err Upgrade tool signature                                                                                                                                              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]                                                                                                                                  
Err Upgrade tool                                                                                                                                                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]                                                                                                                                  
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                               
WARNING:root:file 'utopic.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.
```

**How should I resolve this problem so that I can `do-release-upgrade`?**